# AlertDialog in PreferenceFragment crashes app

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-alertdialog, android-context

I'm trying to create an `AlertDialog` in my `PreferenceFragment` so the user can confirm that he/she wants to delete all user data.

This is the code I've made:

```
public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Bundle b = getArguments();
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);


    Preference button = (Preference)findPreference(getString(R.string.Delete_user_info));
    button.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {
        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
            //An Alertbuilder
            new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext()) //THIS LINE CRASHES THE APP
                    .setMessage("Do you really want to permanently delete your likes?\nYou will not be able to restore them!!")
                    .setCancelable(true)
                    .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                            new DeleteUserInfo().execute();
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                            dialogInterface.cancel();
                        }
                    })
                    .create()
                    .show();
            return true;
        }
    });
}
}
```

And this is the result in LogCat:

```
11-01 18:58:38.501 29821-29821/com.astudio.andreas.mapstest E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-01 18:58:38.501 29821-29821/com.astudio.andreas.mapstest E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.astudio.andreas.mapstest, PID: 29821
11-01 18:58:38.501 29821-29821/com.astudio.andreas.mapstest E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method getContext()Landroid/content/Context; in class Lcom/astudio/andreas/mapstest/SettingsFragment; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.astudio.andreas.mapstest.SettingsFragment' appears in /data/app/com.astudio.andreas.mapstest-1/base.apk)
11-01 18:58:38.501 29821-29821/com.astudio.andreas.mapstest E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.astudio.andreas.mapstest.SettingsFragment$1.onPreferenceClick(SettingsFragment.java:41)
```

Any ideas on how I can reference the `Context` correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `getActivity()` instead of `getContext()`.

Comment: Thought I had tried that. Slightly embarrassed now. Thanks a lot!